# How can I send an error from my server to the client after a post request?

Tags: node.js, post, error-handling, server, try-catch

I have the following problem: I want to post some Json Data to my Node.js server and in my server I want to check if the email has a specific ending and if the name is part of the email. If not I want to send an error message to the client. The problem is that because of the catch it only alerts "Something went wrong" when the mail/name doesn't match. How can I make it work that I can send a specific error message from the server to the client ?

```
try {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  });
  const json = await response.json();
  console.log(json); 
  window.location.assign(`http://localhost:3000/blog/list`); 
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
    alert("Something went wrong");
  }
```

```
 const post = {
    author: req.body.author,
    email: req.body.email,
  };
  var mail = req.body.email
  var name = req.body.author;
  var validMail = mail.indexOf("gmail.com");
  var names = name.split(' ');
  var i = 0;
  var x = false;
  var validNames = [];
  var error = "a error";
  while (i < names.length) {
    validNames.push(mail.indexOf(names[i].toLowerCase()))
    if (validNames[i] > -1) {
      x = true;
    }
    i++;
  }
  if (validMail > -1 && x == true) {  
    posts.push(post);
    res.send(post);
  } else {
    res.send(error);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does the code sample really shows "Something went wrong" on wrong email ? Because it doesnt looks so. The only way for fetch to throw is a dead server or a non json response.

to return an error to the client that you can parse and use you can do that

```
res.status(500).send({error: 'hello i failed'});
```

then in the client you can do it to handle the error :

```
const json = await response.json();
if (json.error) {
  console.log(json.error);
}
```

Comment: And how can I convert the json.error into a string that I can use to display the error as a HTML element?

Comment: if you send a string like me from the server, then on the client you will also receive a string. did you try to console.log it ?

Comment: Can you mark the question as solved please ?

Comment: Console.log works but I can't put it into a variable

Comment: what did you try ? everything can be put in a variable. can you show updated code ?

Comment: `catch(e) {
             const json = await response.json();
             if (json.error) {
               const errorServer = document.getElementById("errorServer");
               const messageServer = json.error;
               errorServer.innerText = messageServer.join();
               console.log(json.error);
             }`

Comment: why the strange call messageServer.join(). just do { const json = await response.json(); if (json.error) { document.getElementById("errorServer").innerText = json.error; }